# ¿Reuniones virtuales mensuales para celebración de cumpleaños?

Tags: discusión

¿Se animarían a reunirse vía skype/Hangouts una vez al mes para celebrar los cumpleaños de los integrantes de SOes?

Salió la idea en la sala de chat, ¿se imaginan todos con un alguna bebida como un café o una cerveza, celebrando el cumpleaños de los que estén presentes?

¿Opiniones?

Comment: Creo que la distancia media entre los habituales del chat es de varios centenares de quilómetros... ¡te refieres *virtualmente*! ¿Por qué necesitamos una excusa para reunirnos si existe el chat?

Comment: Sería interesante leer más opiniones antes de ver negativos. Van - 6 y sólo 1 comentario por partes del maestro del C++. @PaperBirdMaster para responder a tu pregunta solo tengo una palabra: integración. Me acabas de dar una buena idea :D Quizás no sea "adecuado" hacer algo así público, podríamos usar el mismo chat para invitar por hangout/skype a quienes tengan tiempo. Gracias por haber comentado :D

Comment: Sugiero que los interesados simplemente lo hagan y publiquen un aviso para que se una el que quiera, y si si les sale bien un par de veces pedir a un moderador ♦ que cree un evento de comunidad para que se muestre en el boletín de la comunidad (el recuadro donde están los los enlaces Destacado en Meta, Publicaciones populares en Meta y etc.)

Answer (score 7):

El cumpleaños está sobrevalorado. Es una celebración arbitraria localizada en un punto del tiempo que coincide con múltiplos de 8766,152712096 horas desde el (presunto) momento de nuestro nacimiento.

¿De verdad hay que esperar a que se cumpla esa condición para pasar un buen rato con la gente del chat que nos aprecia? No lo creo. Algunas personas han tomado la costumbre de entrar en el chat general de SOes porque disfrutan de la compañía de los presentes (¡no para hablar de programación!) ¿Acaso hay algo más especial que eso? ¿Cómo pretendemos hacerlo **aún más** especial?

Opino que Tener un canal oficial de Skype, Hangouts (o Telegram, WhatsApp, Discord, TeamSpeak…) en que escucharnos las caras o vernos las voces<sup>1</sup> puede ser un aporte interesante, pero no para celebrar cumpleaños si no por profundizar aquellos vínculos que se deseen profundizar.

---

1. ¿Se te ha lenguado la traba?

Comment: ""en que escucharnos las caras o vernos las voces" XD!!!!!!!!!!!!! Esto -> "puede ser un aporte interesante, pero no para celebrar cumpleaños si no por profundizar aquellos vínculos que se deseen profundizar"

Comment: Voto por un canal de Telegram, ¿alguien mas?

Comment: Hace poco hice uno llamado "Desarrolladores Hispanos" ¿se unen?